# Kubernetes Auth Type not working as VaultBackend in Airflow

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, hashicorp-vault

I am integration Airflow with Vault using the VaultBackend provided under **airflow.contrib.secrets.hashicorp_vault.VaultBackend** or **airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend.**
I installed `apache-airflow-backport-providers-hashicorp` backport package as it has support for various auth types. Vault & Airflow are installed inside minikube using helm charts.

Then through DAG file, using KubernetesPodOperator, I simply run a pod to execute below curl :

`passing = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default', service_account_name="vault-auth", image="alpine:3.7", cmds=["sh", "-cx"], arguments=["apk add curl && curl --request POST \ --data '{"'"jwt"'": "'"$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"'", "'"role"'": "'"example"'"}' \ http://${VAULT_ADDR}/v1/auth/kubernetes/login "], labels={"test-airflow": "firstversion"}, name="passing-test", task_id="passing-task", get_logs=True, dag=dag )`

I received the vault token as client_token.

I tried to connect vault through 2 methods. First using default token as auth type and passing above received token

`os.environ['AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND'] = "airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend" os.environ['AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS'] = '{"connections_path": "myapp", "mount_point": "secret", "auth_type": "token", "token": "$TOKEN", "url": "http://vault:8200"}'`

And second using kubernetes as auth type.

```
os.environ['AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS'] = '{"connections_path": "myapp", "auth_mount_point": "kubernetes", "mount_point": "secret", "auth_type": "kubernetes", "kubernetes_role": "example", "kubernetes_jwt_path":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token", "url": "http://vault:8200"}'
```

But for both it gives same error.

> Error: File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hvac/utils.py", line
> 47, in raise_for_error raise exceptions.InternalServerError(message,
> errors=errors, method=method, url=url)
> hvac.exceptions.InternalServerError: service account name not
> authorized, on post http://vault:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login

Please suggest a way to work out kubernetes auth login to access vault token in airflow.